# PHP Mail_Mime: How to properly use encodeHeader() on the body of an email

Tags: php, email, pear, mime

How do I fix the character encoding for this:

```
require_once(/Mail/mime.php");

$corpoTxt = 'Teste envio relatórios são';
$corpoHtml= '<html><body>Versão HTML do texto</body></html>';
```

I tried:

```
$corpoTxt=$mime->encodeHeader("corpo", $corpoTxt, "utf-8", "quoted-printable");
$corpoHtml=$mime->encodeHeader("corpohtmls", $corpoHtml, "utf-8", "quoted-printable");
```

But it doesn't work, I get:

```
VersÃ£o HTML do texto
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try including these lines prior to calling the $mine-headers() function.

```
# Ensure EML is UTF-8 compliant
$mimeparams["debug"] = "True";
$mimeparams['text_encoding'] = "8bit";
$mimeparams['text_charset'] = "UTF-8";
$mimeparams['html_charset'] = "UTF-8";
$mimeparams['head_charset'] = "UTF-8";
$mime->get($mimeparams);
```

This will ensure your UTF-8 characters will display properly in the EML. Finally, save the TXT and HTML body like so:

```
    $mime->setTXTBody($corpoTxt);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($corpoHtml);
```

That should work. For more help, have a look at:

[Pear Mail, how to send plain/text + text/html in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783435/pear-mail-how-to-send-plain-text-text-html-in-utf-8)