UTF8 characters in PEAR Mail
I'm using the PEAR Mail package to send a message through a contact form via (external) SMTP. The web pages are encoded in utf8 and echoing the form variables displays them correctly.
However, international characters (čšđž) are not being sent properly (when I view the resulting email, Reply-To name and message body don't display correctly). Reading the email in my inbox I see the header is set as charset=ISO-8859-1.
Is this an issue with PEAR Mail or my SMTP provider, and how can I fix it? I.e., how can i send non-ascii characters in smtp email header and body?
 //email send
            require_once "Mail.php";
            require_once "Mail/mime.php";
            
            $from = "<noreply@example.com>";
            $to = "<inbox@example.com>";
            $subject = "Message from form";
            $text = $_POST["body"];

            $replyTo = $_POST["senderName"] . " <" . $_POST["senderEmail"] . ">";
            $mime = new Mail_mime();
            $mime->setTXTBody($text);
            $body = $mime->get();
            
            $host = "ssl://mail.censoredsmtpprovider.com";
            $port = "465";
            // 8465 can also be used.
            
            $username = "censored";
            $password = "censored";
            
            $headers = array (

/*'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', TRIED THIS WITH NO EFFECT */
            'From' => $from,
              'Reply-To' => $replyTo,
              'To' => $to,
              'Subject' => $subject);
            $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
                'port' => $port,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password));
            
            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

The only probable solution I've found (have not tested yet) is here, but the answer is 15 years old so I'm wondering if anything has changed in the meantime.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783435/pear-mail-how-to-send-plain-text-text-html-in-utf-8? (I haven't seen PEAR in awhile, Swift or PHPMailer are mailing platforms I generally see used)

Thanks... I decided to go with PHPMailer and was up and running in 5 minutes.
